# Javascript await in imbricated loop error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to understand to to imbricate loops in javascript and call an imported async function from an async script and I get an error. It seems like ReadinglogManager.getReadingLogForAPeriod cannot be call with await?

Main code:

```
var myfunction = async function(req, res, next){
students.forEach(function(s) {
            
            dateobj.forEach(function(d) {
               console.log('Date: '+d.toString())
                let st= new Date();
           
                const rl = await ReadinglogManager.getReadingLogForAPeriod(st,s.uid );

            });

        });
}
```

From ReadinglogManager:

```
var getReadingLogForAPeriod = async function(start_date, student_uid){
   
    let db = DatabaseManager.fs.firestore();
    let dataset = [];
    let snapshot = await db.collection('ReadingLog').where('date', '>=', start_date).where('student_uid', '=', student_uid).get();
  //  dataset = await DatabaseManager.snapshot_to_resultset(snapshot);
    await snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let tdoc=doc.data();
        tdoc.uid=doc.id;
        console.log("DOC: "+JSON.stringify(tdoc));
        dataset.push(tdoc);
    });
    return Promise.resolve(dataset);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `await` can only be used within an `async` function and the callback function (the `function(d) {}` part) is not async so such using will result in an error.

Also changing it to `async function(d) {}` does not solve the problem neither. Because `forEach` does not expect its callback to be an async function and does not `await` its asynchronous execution.

So for such cases you should use plain loop instead of `forEach`, like:

```
var myfunction = async function(req, res, next){
  for(let n = 0;i<students.length;++i){
     let s = students[n];
     for(let i = 0;i<dateobj.length;++i){
        let d = dateobj[i];
        console.log('Date: '+d.toString())
        let st= new Date();
        const rl = await ReadinglogManager.getReadingLogForAPeriod(st,s.uid );
     }
  }
}
```